# Perturbation of uniformly continuous semigroup

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

I think I can prove the following claim about perturbing semigroups, but this must be known somehow, and I am just reinventing the wheel. Do you have any suggestions for references that treat this, before I include the proof in a publication? Note that the operators $A, B$ in the claim below are bounded linear operators.

Claim: Let $X$ be a Banach space, and let $A, B$ be bounded linear operators on $X$ to itself. The uniformly continuous semigroups generated by $A$ and $B$ satisfy

$$
   \Vert e^{tA}- e^{tB} \Vert \leq  t \Vert A - B \Vert e^{t \Vert A-B \Vert} e^{t \Vert A \Vert},
   \qquad t >0 .
$$.

Comment: The notion of semigroup is not needed. By substituting $U=tA$ and $V=tB$ you claim that $$\|e^U-e^V\|\le \|U-V\| e^{\|U-V\|}e^{\|U\|}$$ It looks strange as the LHS is does not change if you switch $U$ and $V$ unlike the RHS.

Comment: Hi @RyszardSzwarc fair point. I have added to the original question my proof sketch, to see what goes wrong.

Comment: Hi @RyszardSzwarc my response to the asymmetry of the bound would be the same one given below by Gerd.

Comment: Could you share the book you are using?

Comment: Your reasoning is incorrect as $e^{t(A+B)}$ is usually not equal $ e^{tA}e^{tB}$ unless $A$ and $B$ commute.

Comment: @Akira if you are referring to the screenshot in the question I posed, that's not a book, but a draft of a paper I'm writing. I also think it could be wrong, as it was pointed out above. I am looking into this

Comment: @DanieleAvitabile Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a straight forward consequence of the solution formula for linear ODEs (see below). Elementary estimates of this type are often used but hard to find in exactly the form you need. I would just call it a lemma.

Set $h(t):=e^{tB}-e^{tA}$. Then
$$
h'(t)=Be^{tB}-Ae^{tA}=(B-A)e^{tB} + A(e^{tB}-e^{tA})=(B-A)e^{tB} + Ah(t).
$$
Since $h(0)=0$ we have
$$
h(t)=\int_0^t e^{(t-s)A} (B-A)e^{sB} ds.
$$
Thus
$$
\|h(t)\| \le \int_0^t e^{(t-s)\|A\|} \|B-A\|e^{s\|B\|} ds = \int_0^t e^{t\|A\|} \|B-A\|e^{s(\|B\|-\|A\|)} ds 
$$
$$
\le \int_0^t e^{t\|A\|} \|B-A\|e^{s\|A-B\|} ds \le \int_0^t e^{t\|A\|} \|B-A\|e^{t\|A-B\|} ds = t \|A-B\|e^{t\|A-B\|}e^{t\|A\|}
$$

Comment: Nice! I would have never thought about the ODE argument. I attached my own argument to the original question, but @Ryszard Szwarc raised a point above on the inequality.

Comment: @DanieleAvitabile The right hand side is indeed not symmetric in $A$ and $B$. However you can replace $e^{t\|A\|}$ by $e^{t\|B\|}$ (by changing the role of $A$ am $B$), and then you can get a symmetric inequality by $\|e^{tA}-e^{tB} \| \le t\|A-B\| e^{t\|A-B\|} \min\{ e^{t\|A\|},e^{t\|B\|}\}$.

Comment: Yep, that's what came to mind to me too. The bound I found isn't sharp, and one could get a sharper bound by using the min.

Comment: Hi @Gerd you can read below the answer I gave (I did find a reference for the Banach space version, which is similar to your integral equality). I also pointed out that you will feature in the acknowledgments of the manuscript. I hope this is fine with you, and let me know otherwise.

Comment: @DanieleAvitabile I read your answer and it looks fine to me.  It's always nice to be mentioned in the acknowledgments.

Answer (score 1):

A sligthly sharper estimate can be obtained by  entirely elementary methods, namely
$$\|e^A-e^B\|\le \|A-B\|e^{\max\{\|A\|,\|B\|\}}$$
WLOG we may assume that $\|A\|\ge \|B\|.$ First we will consider the case $\|A\|>\|B\|.$ We have
$$e^A-e^B=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over n!} (A^n-B^n)\quad (*)$$
Next $$A^n-B^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} [A^{n-k}B^k-A^{n-k-1}B^{k+1}]=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A^{n-k-1}(A-B)B^k$$
Thus
$$\|A^n-B^n\|\le \|A-B\|\,\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\|A\|^{n-k-1}\|B\|^k\quad (**)\\
={\|A-B\|\over \|A\|-\|B\|}(\|A\|^n-\|B\|^n)$$
Applying $(*)$ we get
$$\|e^A-e^B\|\le {\|A-B\|\over \|A\|-\|B\|}\sum_{n=0}^\infty{1\over n!}[\|A\|^n-\|B\|^n]\\  =\|A-B\|\,{e^{\|A\|}-e^{\|B\|}\over \|A\|-\|B\|}$$
By MVT the  ratio is equal $e^x$ for some $x,$ such that $\|B\|<x<\|A\|.$ Therefore
$$\|e^A-e^B\|\le \|A-B\|\,e^{\|A\|}$$
If $\|A\|=\|B\|$ the estimate $(**)$ takes the form
$$\|A^n-B^n\|\le \|A-B\|\,n\|A\|^{n-1}$$ Thus
$$\|e^A-e^B\|\le \|A-B\|\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\|A\|^{n-1}\over (n-1)!}=\|A-B\|\,e^{\|A\|}$$
By substituting $A:=tA$ and $B:=tB$, $t>0,$ we get
$$\|e^{tA}-e^{tB}\|\le t\|A-B\|e^{t\max\{\|A\|,\|B\|\}} \quad (***)$$
The estimate is stronger than the one provided in OP as
$$\|A-B\|+\min\{\|A\|,\|B\|\}\ge \max\{\|A\|,\|B\|\}$$
Indeed if $\|A\|\ge \|B\|,$ then $\|A-B\|+\|B\|\ge \|A\|$ by the triangle inequality.

**Remark** The approach provided by @Gerd is much more popular and gives the answer faster. It can be easily modified at one place to give $(***).$

Comment: Hi @RyszardSzwarc, thank you very much for spotting the error in my proof. I have ended up using Gerd's proof as it is quicker. You can read below the answer I gave. I also pointed out that you will feature in the acknowledgments of the manuscript. I hope this is fine with you, and let me know otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I have now found a reference that can help with the integral equality that Gerd uses above, but in the context of Banach spaces, namely Engel and Nagel, A short course on operator semigroups. I post below the current proof I give. Gerd and Ryszard figure both in the acknowledgment section of the manuscript I am preparing.

Below is a screenshot of the current proof

[image]